# Django - How to annotate QuerySet using multiple field values?

Tags: django, sorting, aggregation, django-queryset, annotate

I have a model called "Story" that has two integer fields called "views" and "votes". When I retrieve all the Story objects I would like to annotate the returned QuerySet with a "ranking" field that is simply "views"/"votes". Then I would like to sort the QuerySet by "ranking". Something along the lines of...

```
Story.objects.annotate( ranking=CalcRanking('views','votes') ).sort_by(ranking)
```

How can I do this in Django? Or should it be done after the QuerySet is retrieved in Python (like creating a list that contains the ranking for each object in the QuerySet)?

Thanks!

PS: In my actual program, the ranking calculation isn't as simple as above and depends on other filters to the initial QuerySet, so I can't store it as another field in the Story model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django, the things you can pass to `annotate` (and `aggregate`) must be subclasses of `django.db.models.aggregates.Aggregate`. You can't just pass arbitrary Python objects to it, since the aggregation/annotation actually happens inside the database (that's the whole point of `aggregate` and `annotate`). Note that writing custom aggregations is not supported in Django (there is no documentation for it). All information available on it is this minimal source code: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/aggregates.py

This means you either have to store the calculations in the database somehow, figure out how the aggregation API works or use raw sql (`raw` method on the Manager) to do what you do.